# Передать аргументы из переменных в SQL-запрос

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

Есть таблица, в которой я хочу изменить какую-либо запись:

```
def insertUser(ID, AUTHOR):
con = lite.connect("something.db")
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = """UPDATE someth
            SET used = 1, 
            dis_name = ?, 
            dis_id = ?
            WHERE used = '0' """
    cur.execute(sql, (ID, AUTHOR))
```

Таким образом не выходит. И еще подскажите, пожалуйста, в моей таблице есть поле **used**, в котором по умолчанию во всех записях `0`, мне нужно, чтобы запрос обновлял первую попавшуюся запись, где **used** равно `0`, а остальные не трогал.

Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для конкатенции строки с переменными вы можете использовать один из следующих вариантов:

- Обычная конкатенция оператором +
- Форматирования с помощью оператора %
- Использовать метод format() для строк
- Использовать f-строки (только для python 3)

Пример с использованием метода `.format()`

```
def insertUser(ID, AUTHOR): 
    con = lite.connect("something.db")     
    with con: 
        cur = con.cursor() 
        sql = """UPDATE someth 
                 SET used = 1, dis_name = {}, dis_id = {}
                 WHERE used = 0
                 ORDER BY id ASC
                 LIMIT 1""".format(AUTHOR, ID)
        cur.execute(sql)
```

Для того, чтобы обновить только первую запись, необходимо использовать команду LIMIT с значением 1 вместе ORDER BY (для сортировки по ключевому полю). В примере использована колонка id (как правило, так обозначают в таблицах primary key поля). Если у вас нет такого поля, можете заменить на существующее

**UPDATE**:

Если вы используете sqlite, скомпилированную без объявления опции

```
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT
```

То предыдущий код работать не будет, но вы можете реализовать аналог с помощью подзапроса:

```
def insertUser(ID, AUTHOR): 
        con = lite.connect("something.db")     
        with con: 
            cur = con.cursor() 
            sql = """UPDATE someth 
                     SET used = 1, dis_name = {}, dis_id = {}
                     WHERE used = (
                         SELECT id FROM someth 
                         WHERE id = 0
                         ORDER BY id ASC
                         LIMIT 1)
            """.format(AUTHOR, ID)
            cur.execute(sql)
```

Либо перекомпировать sqlite согласно [инструкции](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/master/README.md) с включенной опцией SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT

Comment: Благодарю вас за предложенные варианты! Но в вашем примере у меня появляется ошибка: *OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error*

Comment: @НикитаВиноградов , странно. попробуйте добавить явное указание порядка сортировки ASC (добавил в ответ).

Comment: нет, к сожалению, ошибка не исчезла :(

Comment: @НикитаВиноградов, у вас есть колонка id в этой таблице или вы другую подставляете?

Comment: @НикитаВиноградов , попробуйте так же убрать одинарные кавычки

Comment: @НикитаВиноградов , если вы используете sqlite, вероятно, она скомпилирована с отключенным флагом SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT

Comment: id есть, кавычки убрал, пока все также. не подскажете,как оперировать с *SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT*? ранее, к сожалению, не сталкивался. да, sqlite

Comment: @НикитаВиноградов , обновил ответ